# Adding multiple hashes not working for Content Security Policy

Tags: c#, google-chrome, blazor, blazor-server-side, content-security-policy

I have a Blazor server-side app and I added the following the `<head>` of `_Host.cshtml`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="base-uri 'self';
               default-src 'self';
               img-src data: https:;
               object-src 'none';
               script-src 'self';
               style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
               upgrade-insecure-requests;">
```

I originally all the hashes that were reported in the console. But the errors are still reported. I had to remove the hashes and add `unsafe-inline`. I'd rather have the hashes instead.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the hashes are for inline event attributes such as onclick, onload etc. These can't be hashed, but the browser provides them in the errors anyway. You will need to rewrite with event listeners.